# How do I fix AdMob crashing my Android app?

Tags: java, android, admob

AdMob has been working in my Android app for a while now until recently when I tried to update. I tried to update the app itself but I saw that it kept crashing.

I tried debugging what happened. The app seems to work once I removed the ads. I've now published the app without any ads and it works fine. Any reasons why it may have all of a sudden stopped working? I haven't changed any of the code before. The only code I changed were additional tips in my Relationship tips app.

Comment: What error are you getting?  noclassdeffounderror?

Comment: there is no error it just crashes when i open it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure your jar files are checked in Properties --> Java Build Path --> Order and Export.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post error so I am just guessing, admob had a bug on android os 2.1+, and I had a admob crashing issue, I found a suggestion to not calling adview.destroy on OnDestroy because it causes crashing.

If you have adview.destroy() on your onDestroy override, just remark it and try.

```
  @Override
  protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    // bug at sdk, no need to call
    //adView.destroy();
  }
```

Comment: Like I said there is no error message, it just crashes when I try to run the app.

Comment: if (adView != null) adView.destroy();